# How to use ~/.vimrc for vimdiff

Tags: vimdiff, git

How can I get git's `difftool`, when using `vimdiff`, to use my `~/.vimrc` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my `git` config, I have alias:

```
[alias]
   vimdiff=difftol -y -t vimdiff -R
```

This *does* use my .vimrc to display all colorscheme, statusline, etc.